# How To Get MathJax In-Line Maths To Work On GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, github-pages, mathjax

I am using GitHub Pages to host a site of maths resources. I have implemented MathJax on the site, and this works locally; however, when the Page is viewed on a desktop, the in-line maths doesn't work.

I saw, as linked elsewhere, to use two script tags, those being  `<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>` and `<script>MathJax = {tex: {inlineMath: [["$", "$"]]}}</script>`. However, those are what I had already implemented. The maths not in-line works fine on all devices, but the in-line maths only works when the files are on my desktop, or when the Pages site is viewed on mobile.

The photos below are screenshots from the same page ([here](https://azorbz.github.io/atlasmaths/normed-spaces-21-05-2023.html)):

[When the files are on my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC9iq.png)

[The GitHub Pages site (desktop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCHSN.png)

[The GitHub Pages site (mobile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfj6t.jpg)